# TestFlight notification going out for old builds instead of the recent one

Tags: testflight

When we add users to a new build in TestFlight, for some reason, they get a notification (including an email) about an old build. If they open TestFlight, they'll see the new build, but the notifications they receive are about the old build.

Is this a TestFlight bug, or is there some config we don't know about? I can't imagine that this would be expected behavior.